# What is an Objective-C "class continuation"?

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, syntax, automatic-ref-counting

I can't quite figure out what I have seen *referred to as* an Objective-C **"class continuation"**.  Is this / are these…

1. Ivar(s) declared in the `@implementation` (`.m`) file?
2. Another name for a class category? (Unlikely, *ASFAIK* categories cannot have Ivars, period)
3. Another name for a class extension?
4. Something else?

*That said...*

1. What is the scope, lifetime, and usage case for such a thing?
2. Is this an ARC-specific "feature"?
3. Are there specific runtime, or other requirements for their use?
4. Is this an appropriate place to create an `@property`, as well? And why would this be a better place for setting ivars or properties than, say, the `@interface` file / declaration?
5. Why do people complicate discussions by using such specific terminology - that seems NOT to exist in any official documentation (that I could find)?

In question [In Objective-C what is the difference between defining something (say a property) in the header file as opposed to the .m file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042480/in-objective-c-what-is-the-difference-between-defining-something-say-a-property)
the discussion touches on this issue, but sort of just clouds the issue further - or at least fails to provide a canonical reference / definition of the term… hence this question.

Comment: From a comment in the linked question.. "The correct term for an 'anonymous category' is a 'class continuation'. It is different from categories in that it can contain additional fields." or some other questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172598/best-way-to-define-private-methods-for-a-class-in-objective-c) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827242/can-i-create-properties-with-a-public-getter-and-private-setter)

Comment: The quote is actually a very bad description of class extensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *continuation class* is what Apple calls a [*class extension*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2). I have seen clang call them "continuation class" and gcc uses "class continuation".

Compile this in clang or gcc:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property int a;
@end

@interface Foo()
@property float a;
@end
```

... and you will get errors with the funny names.

To answer the rest of your question:

> 1. What is the scope, lifetime, and usage case for such a thing?

Extensions are used to declare the private interface for a class. You can also use it to redeclare (refine) public property declarations.

> 2. Is this an ARC-specific "feature"?

NO.

> 3. Are there specific runtime, or other requirements for their use?

Class Extensions are a compile time concept and do not require a special runtime. Of course they do require a compiler that supports them (both clang and gcc do in current versions).

> 4. Is this an appropriate place to create an @property, as well? And why would this be a better place for setting ivars or properties than, say, the @interface file / declaration?

YES. Because you might want to have private properties.

> 5. Why do people complicate discussions by using such specific terminology - that seems NOT to exist in any official documentation (that I could find)?

Well, you know... I'd also prefer if the whole world spoke English, but for the time being I'm happy with the fact that I had to learn it in school.

Comment: before the non-fragile abi (ie. 32 bit) the extension is much more of a normal category and can not be used to declare private ivars...

Comment: Declaring private ivars is of course dependent on the Objective-C 2.0's runtime, whether they are declared in the class extension or the @implementation. Putting them in the class extension is only supported in clang. The features of class extensions are not touched by this.

Comment: I find comparing class extensions with categories is not helpful. While the syntax is similar they serve a different purpose and have other compile time and run time characteristics.

Comment: ok, that doesn't change the fact that you cant declare an ivar in an extension on 32-bit mac, clang or no clang. you also can't synthesize your backing iVar for properties... because the runtime doesn't support it.

Comment: Please file a bug against the misuse of the name in the compiler.  Note that "class extensions" were briefly called "class continuations" during development.

Comment: In what case do you want to redeclare a public property as specified in (1)?

Comment: @Boon The question is not about code but about terminology and I needed a snippet to provoke the compiler to emit an error that refers to the class extension.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe You mentioned in (1) that you can also use it to redeclare public property declaration.  My question is - why or when will there be such a need?

Comment: @Boon Oh, sorry, I misread your question. Redeclaring a property can make sense in several scenarios. It's most often used when a property is publicly `readonly` and privately `readwrite`. In this case a setter will be generated but it will be only accessible in the `@implementation`. Other cases include a publicly immutable collection that is privately mutable.

Comment: Update the official doc address for [class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3)