# Core Data, iVars and Categories

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data, categories

One of my core data subclasses has an `NSSet` of `items`. It is often (but not always, so no `NSOrderedSet`) useful to instead retrieve an ordered `NSArray`, so I added `orderedItems` to the class, which sorts them.

I then ran into performance issues so decided to try caching the `orderedItems`. My plan is to use an iVar, `_cachedOrderedItems` in the class, which I will return if it is not null.

The snag comes with my use of categories. I read some good advice about putting all of my custom code in a category so that I can re-generate the core data class if necessary and not lose all my customizations. One of those customizations is the `orderedItems` method.

It seems I can not declare an iVar in the category itself. And if I try to put it in the core data class instead, I can not access it in the category.

Do I need to move my custom code back into the core data class? Or am I missing something?

I have also heard about Mogenerator, and would consider learning to use this if it would help.

Comment: And maybe I should be using a subclass and not a category for my custom code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to add ivars to a class any time you can't modify the original class, including in categories. For a detailed example, see [Faking instance variables in Objective-C categories with Associative References](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/).

Answer (score 1):

You own the class, so you can use a class continuation (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301661/what-is-an-objective-c-class-continuation)) instead of a category. This allows you to add instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use mogenerator. See for example http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2006/12/19/mogenerator-or-how-i-nearly-abandoned-core-data/.

You can make an Aggregate target in XCode, add a Run Script with the following:

```
mogenerator -m path/to/your/datamodel.xcdatamodeld/version.xcdatamodel --template-var arc=true -M /CoreData/Generated -H /CoreData
```

For every `NSManagedObject` you get a class and a subclass. When updating your datamodel, run the script again and the base class will be updated, preserving all the changes you made to the managed object subclass. Remove `--template-var arc=true` for none arc.